# Dynamically inject content into JSDoc @example

Tags: jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc to document my javascript API.

I have an `@example` where I exhibit a minimized loader script (similar to the Google Analytics script). The loader script loads additional javascript from `https://<server>/myProduct/lib/script.js`.

My JSDoc documentation is bundled with `myProduct`, so there are aways `/myProduct/lib/script.js` and `/myProduct/docs/` side-by-side. However, `myProduct` can be hosted by my customers anywhere, so I don't know what the `<server>` is.

I would like to be able to use `document.location.href` to detect current browser URL, and display a working loader script in my `@example`, so that customer can simply copy & paste a working script from documentation without having to manually edit the `<server>` part.

**My question is:** Does JSDoc offer any means to dynamically inject content into `@example`?

I could just manually edit the JSDoc output and include some custom javascript manually, which replaces `<server>` with the actual current server on run-time. However, this would be tedious to do every time my documentation updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JsDoc doesn't provide for injecting external content, and while it is certainly possible to create a JsDoc plugin to include external content during document generation, I don't think this would get you where you need to be.

I think the simplest answer would be to post-process the output of JsDoc to add a simple script, like

```
<script>
// retrieve the hostname from the current url.
const getServiceHostName = () => 
  document.location.href.replace(/http:\/\/([\/]+)\/.+$/, '$1');

// replace the content of the span#service-host with the current hostname.
document.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("service-host").textContent=getServiceHostName();
};
</script>
```

to your html files just above the `</body>` tag.

Then, in the example content, insert a `<span id="service-host"></span>` where you'd like the service hostname to appear.

Another approach might be to take advantage of the fact that JsDoc passes the content attached to the @description tag directly into the html output.

So, this appears to do the expected:

```
/**
 * Hostname: "<span id="service-host">hostname</span>"
 *
 * <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
 *   integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
 *   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 *
 * <script>
 *   $(document).ready(function() {
 *     $("#service-host").html(document.location.href);
 *   });
 * </script>
 *
 * @name How-To-Monkey-Patch-JsDoc
 *
 */
```

Note that the content of `@example` is wrapped in `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` in the html output which will definitely cause you problems, but it should be easy to post-process the html inline using the code above, by adding some recognizable token (perhaps `[[HOSTNAME]]`) into the example content and on document load, replace it with the desired value.

Please note also that this approach has the possibility of opening your docs to security issues, which is why I'd use the first solution above.

Comment: Thanks Rob - I actually reached the same conclusion. I added a step to my deployment pipeline which injects a <script> into JSDoc main file, which then does post-processing.